# Is Pentaho ETL and Data Analyzer good choice?

Tags: etl, pentaho, star-schema

I was looking for ETL tool and on google found lot about Pentaho Kettle.

I also need a Data Analyzer to run on Star Schema so that business user can play around and generate any kind of report or matrix. Again PentaHo Analyzer is looking good.

Other part of the application will be developed in java and the application should be database agnostic.

Is Pentaho good enough or there are other tools I should check.

Answer (score 3):

Pentaho seems to be pretty solid, offering the whole suite of BI tools, with improved integration reportedly on the way. But...the chances are that companies wanting to go the open source route for their BI solution are also most likely to end up using open source database technology...and in **that** sense "database agnostic" can easily be a double-edged sword. For instance, you can develop a cube in Microsoft's Analysis Services in the comfortable knowledge that whatver MDX/XMLA your cube sends to the database will be intrepeted consistently, holding very little in the way of nasty surprises.

Compare that to the Pentaho stack, which will typically end interacting with Postgresql or Mysql. I can't vouch for how Postgresql performs in the OLAP realm, but I do know from experience that Mysql - for all its undoubted strengths - has "issues" with the types of SQL that typically crops up all over the place in an OLAP solution (you can't get far in a cube without using `GROUP BY` or `COUNT DISTINCT`). So part of what you save in licence costs will almost certainly be used to solve issues arising from the fact the Pentaho doesn't always know which database it is talking to - robbing Peter to (at least partially) pay Paul, so to speak.

Comment: Actually there seems to be more and more Pentaho users starting to use the various open source column db's (e.g. Lucid) instead of mysql and then you can get blinding performance from olap type queries.

Also analysis does do a good job of caching - so even if the queries are slow in the underlying db, it's only a one-off hit.

Finally; It supports aggregate tables - yet another way of avoiding those slow queries - and the aggregation designer sorts all this out for you - It's a very handy tool.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, more info is needed.  For example:

- will you need to exchange data with well-known apps (Oracle Financials, Remedy, etc)?  If so, you can save a ton of time & money with an ETL solution that has support for that interface already built-in.
- what database products (and versions) and file types do you need to talk to?
- do you need to support querying of web-services?
- do you need near real-time trickling of data?
- do you need rule-level auditing & counts for accounting for every single row
- do you need delta processing?
- what kinds of machines do you need this to run on?  linux? windows? mainframe?
- what kind of version control, testing and build processes will this tool have to comply with?
- what kind of performance & scalability do you need?
- do you mind if the database ends up driving the transformations?
- do you need this to run in userspace?
- do you need to run parts of it on various networks disconnected from the rest? (not uncommon for extract processes)
- how many interfaces and of what complexity do you need to support?

You can spend a lot of time deploying and learning an ETL tool - only to discover that it really doesn't meet your needs very well.  You're best off taking a couple of hours to figure that out first.

Comment: thanks for your parameters to choose the tool...... i will certainly validate that for Pentaho. If consider answer is true for all your questions do you Pentaho comes good?

Comment: Well, it's a quick high-level list.  I'd also consider licensing - since there are critical features missing from the free version (like remote admin & alerting).

And I'd also consider how badly you want a model-driven approach.  Personally, I find that model-driven ETL is a PITA for 20% or so of the work.  What I like the most is a toolbox of libraries & tools for python/ruby/java/perl to then interact with.  For many small projects just building your own libraries is the superior solution to learning a large product and dealing with another vendor.

Comment: Curious; In what way does the paid version have alerting?

Comment: Sorry - I can't find my notes on Pentaho's ETL product anymore to confirm.  In the above comment I probably meant alerting if processes fail via SMS messaging, not alerting like an OLAP tool would do.  This comment was from over a year ago and may be obsolete, though the tendency for dual-licensed products to reserve their best features for the commercial version is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Talend](http://www.talend.com/index.php) before with some success. You create your translation by chaining operations together in a graphical designer. There were definitely some WTF's and it was difficult to deal with multi-line records, but it worked well otherwise.

Talend also generates Java and you can access the ETL processes remotely. The tool is also free, although they provide enterprise training and support.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of choices.   Look at BIRT, Talend and Pentaho, if you want free tools.   If you want much more robustness, look at Tableau and BIRT Analytics.